# Why won't the game "Ultima I" work on my Apple IIe system?

Tags: apple-ii, undocumented-opcodes

I'm trying to complete the original Ultima I on an Apple //e.

[These instructions](http://guides.gamercorner.net/ultimai/space/) explain space flight, but I can't seem to destroy enemy ships in order to become a Space Ace, even when I should be able to.

Comment: Game play specific questions feel off-topic here. Those other sources are probably always going to be as good as it gets.

Comment: @jdv: But not good enough in this case, as my answer illustrates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because gameplay-specific questions should be asked on Gaming.SE.

Comment: If you want this to be on-topic, you need to make clear that it's a technical problem, not a gameplay one.  "I can't seem to destroy enemy ships" is very vague.

Comment: @Mark: Have you read this meta question? http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/71/are-retro-games-on-topic

Comment: this is off topic since it's gameplay related.

Comment: @Thomas You're 8 months late, mate.This was the first test question on that topic as discussed in meta 8 months ago and it's already been closed. Your downvote and comment are redundant.

Comment: sorry, didn't pay attention; I just discovered this subsection, so I've been going through the posts, but I didn't look at the dates

Answer (score 12):

Are you using an enhanced //e? If so you'll need to get a patched copy, or copy and [patch yours](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.sys.apple2/ultima$20space$20ace/comp.sys.apple2/rEwRhM5hsHI/Z7knStMvSvUJ).

The original (non-remake) Apple II version uses an undocumented 6502 opcode in the space flight code. This makes it impossible to hit the alien ships when running on a 65C02.

The fix is in file "FGT3". Change the bytes at 74D1 to 46 43 45 43 (all hex).

Comment: http://www.wiki.ultimacodex.com/wiki/Bugs There is already a game specific wiki for this.

Comment: @jdv: Yes, I added this to the wiki. Ultima is a famous series. Do you want me to find a more obscure example?

Comment: I'd prefer if you use SE in good faith.

Comment: I am AFAIK. You know that it was suggested in meta that I submit a question as a test case. I've seen this question asked before and I think SE is a great place for its like.

Comment: Sure, but he whole thing was contrived, wasn't it? (I saw the meta question and knew this was related, but was unaware it was a "test" question.) Even so, the overwhelming majority of game questions, retro or not, would never come close to a similar answer. This huge majority would just be in-game instructions, and the fact that a game or platform is old or new would have no bearing on the answer. It is not representative of the kind of topic it is supposed to be supporting. At the end of the day, this is a game hack; while it pertains to an ancient system it remains a specific game hack.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking and answering a question you know the answer to if it serves a purpose. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: I'll close with this: specific system tweaks to get software running correctly is IMO on-topic. I said as much in my meta answer. It just feels like rules lawyering to hold up this question as an example that game questions, in general, are somehow on-topic. I still maintain that similarly worded questions are a bad fit for Retro, simply because it is improbable that an obscure system hack is the only solution, and that this solution wasn't captured in a game-specific wiki over a year ago, when that information was copied from a Google forum.

Comment: Sigh. If any other tortured souls make it this far, the meta question is: http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/71/are-retro-games-on-topic

Comment: System specific tweaks are on topic since retro computers are famous for compatibility problems where developers did not follow the _correct_ way of doing things. There is still a significant list of games that do not run on the ROM3 IIgs because of IO changes in the ROM.

Comment: Actually with the discussion of undocumented opcodes and compatibility issues across different computer models, it seems somewhat fitting.  it's also worth noting that there are not many emulators that support undocumented 6502 opcodes on the Apple // series.